# Systemd and SysVinit compatibility mode

Tags: systemd, init-script, init.d

Trying to reuse an existing "SysV" init script with new Linux version that uses "systemd" (RHEL 7). Just copying it into "/etc/init.d/" fails to work as expected. Can only manually Start/Stop service using the commandline as if the script was a user file. The systemd enable and start/stop fail.

Where should "SysV" init scripts be copied to on a system that is using systemd ?
Where should any custom systemd scripts for system/user service daemons be created ?
What are common problems found or required actions before I can use the old init scripts with the new systemd ?